# Ajax - JSON doesnt get sent in PATCH only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send json data from the client to my server using this:

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/pulse/7/',
    data : data,
    type : 'PATCH',
    contentType : 'application/json'
)};
```

I get a `No JSON object could be decoded`.
However when i use `PUT` the json object gets sent.

**It only doesnt work for PATCH**

The backend is Django and the app im using is tastypie

Comment: Does your browser support `PATCH` method?

Comment: I am using the latest version of chrome

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, check that you use latest version of jQuery library:

- Older versions directly restrict unknown methods (PATCH is new one).
- I've tested on jQuery 1.7 - PATCH method working without problems.

Second, not all browsers supports PATCH method using XMLHttpRequest:

- Like, IE 7,8 (9+ works okay) have XMLHttpRequest, but it throws an error on PATCH:

  ```
  new XMLHttpRequest().open('PATCH', '/'); //Illegal argument
  ```
- To fix this, you may force jQuery to use the old proprietary ActiveXObject xhr, like so:

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/pulse/7/',
      data : data,
      type : 'PATCH',
      contentType : 'application/json',
      xhr: function() {
          return window.XMLHttpRequest == null || new window.XMLHttpRequest().addEventListener == null 
              ? new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
              : $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
      }
  });
  ```

Answer (score 16):

A bit late, but this worked for me when I got this error:

```
$.ajax({
  url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/pulse/7/',
  data : JSON.stringify(data),
  type : 'PATCH',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  processData: false,
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Serializing the object yourself instead of letting jQuery do it seems to help.  This works for me on the latest version of Chrome, but still doesn't fix the ie problems mentioned in other responses.

Comment: wow I spent hours trying to solve a django related problem and this was the issue. smh. thank you sir

Answer (score 3):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('PATCH', 'http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/pulse/6/', false);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
request.send('{"isActive": 1}');
```

Using a an XMLHttpRequest solves it!