# Django Tastypie PATCH 401 but PUT is OK

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model and resource. I use ajax to update the resource. I can do PUT but when I do PATCH, it gives me 401.
I wonder where the problem could be.

Model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from freebie.models import Freebie

# Create your models here.

class Claim(models.Model):
    claimer = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='claimer')
    claim_item = models.ForeignKey(Freebie, related_name='claim_item')
    PENDING = 'pending'
    APPROVED = 'approved'
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PENDING, 'pending'),
        (APPROVED, 'approved'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=40,
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=PENDING
    )
```

Resource:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.authentication import SessionAuthentication
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.constants import ALL_WITH_RELATIONS
from claim.models import Claim
from accounts.resources import UserResource
from freebie.resources import FriendsFreebieResource
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class ClaimResource(ModelResource):

    claimer = fields.ToOneField(UserResource, 'claimer', full=True)
    claim_item = fields.ToOneField(FriendsFreebieResource, 'claim_item')

    class Meta:

        queryset = Claim.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'claim'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch']
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {'claimer': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                     'claim_item': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}

    def hydrate(self, bundle):

        # No pk means this is claimer posting the first claim.

        if not bundle.obj.pk:
            bundle.obj.claimer = \
                User.objects.get(pk=bundle.request.user.id)
        else:
            bundle.data['claimer'] = bundle.obj.claimer

        return bundle
```

Ajax, PATCH does not work, gives 401, PUT works fine:

```
var data = {};
data.status = "approved";
$.ajax({
    url:'/api/v1/claim/'+claim_id+"/",
    type:'PATCH', // Change to PUT, everything works.
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(data) {
        $claimer_list.empty();
        var $approved_li = $('<li>')
            .text("Given to " + claim.claimer.first_name + " " + claim.claimer.last_name);
        $claimer_list.append($approved_li);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert(error);
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the jQuery ajax call support PATCH?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642044/does-the-jquery-ajax-call-support-patch)