# Why is my coffeescript submitting an ajax request to the wrong url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I've got a form that's submitted like so:

```
class PreferenceForm
  constructor: (preference_form) ->
    @preference_form = preference_form
    @preview_update_button = @preference_form.find $("[data-behavior='preview-update-button']")
    @submit_url = @preference_form.attr('action')
    @setEvents()

  setEvents: ->
    @preference_form.on "submit", @handleSubmit

  handleSubmit: (event) =>
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log @submit_url
    $.ajax(
      url: @submit_url,
      method: "PATCH"
      dataType: "JSON"
      data: @preference_form.serialize()
      success: @handleSuccess
    )
```

The console logs @submit_url as, `/user_preferences/#` which is correct. However, when I actually try to submit the form, it sends the PATCH request to the current page instead of the url I'm trying to send it to.

What causes this behavior to happen? How can I make it behave the way I intend?

Everything is instantiated like this:

```
class CertificatePreviewer
  constructor: (certificate_previewer) ->
    @certificate_previewer = certificate_previewer
    @preference_form = new PreferenceForm @certificate_previewer.find $("[data-behavior='preference-form']")

jQuery ->
  new CertificatePreviewer $("[data-behavior='certificate-previewer']")
```

Comment: `setEvents: -> @preference_form.on "submit" @handleSubmit` would rather be `setEvents: -> @preference_form.on "submit", @handleSubmit`

Comment: @apneadiving you're correct! it actually has the comma in the code, I deleted it somewhere in the act of trying to get SO formatting working

Comment: btw I dont think jquery supports `patch` does it?

Comment: (Rails usually mimics it doing POST + `_method` attribute)

Comment: I think one of the problems might be that I'm sending serialized data and calling it JSON. gonna change that

Comment: Did u see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642044/does-the-jquery-ajax-call-support-patch

Comment: I did! decided to abandon it temporarily to try something else, and after a short period of finagling, got it working with jquery_ujs. had to leave the coffee behind