# Input data not passing on PATCH request with ajax to Laravel Resource Controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to update data with ajax on PATCH request by laravel resource controller, but when I am dumping the inputs that are returned I get an empty array.
Here is my code, and I am using Laravel 4.2 .

**Route**

```
Route::resource('article','ArticlesController');
```

**Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $input = Input::all();

    print_r($input);
}
```

**JS Code**

```
var data = { 
  edit_art_visibility: "1", 
  edit_article_title: "This is a article heading", 
  edit_article_cat: "1", 
  edit_article_text: "This is a article body i am working…", 
  edit_article_photo_hid: "454336056.jpg", edit_article_id: "1"
  _method: 'PATCH'
}
         $.ajax({
               url : urlRoot+"/article/"+data.edit_article_id,
               type : "PATCH",
               data : data,
               success : function(e){
                   console.log(e);
               }
           });
```

**Output on console**

```
Array(
)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642044/does-the-jquery-ajax-call-support-patch

Comment: Try to use POST i.p.o PATCH

Comment: yes it's work when i am trying type as POST instead of PATCH @Franco

Comment: Normally ajax don't care about the patch method which is needed for Laravel.

Comment: Can you able to see the parameters that is passed in the browser's Network tab ?

Comment: no i can't see in the browser