# Issue while delete record in laravel 5.4 using ajax request?

Tags: php, mysql, routes, laravel-5.4

I want to delete a record using ajax call with laravel 5.4. I tried a lot but delete is is not working means unable to delete records from database.
Here is my View:

```
 <div class="btn-sm btn-danger pull-right delete" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" s data-id="{{$menus->id}}">
                                            <i class="voyager-trash"></i> Delete
                                        </div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

$('.delete').click(function(){
 var id=$(this).data("id");
 var token=$(this).data("token");

$.ajax(
        {
            url: "skillset/delete/"+id,
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: {
                "id": id,
                "_method": 'DELETE',
                "_token": token,
            },
            success: function ()
            {
                console.log("okie");
            }
        });

        console.log("not okie");


})

        });
    </script>
```

Controller:

```
public function delete($id)
    {
echo'hii';

     return $result= Skillset::destroy($id);
    }
```

Route:

```
// Route skill set
           Route::group([
            'as' => 'skillset.',
            'prefix' => 'skillset',
                ], function () use ($namespacePrefix) {
            Route::get('/', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Skillsetcontroller@index', 'as' => 'index']);
            Route::post('/', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Skillsetcontroller@store', 'as' => 'store']);
            Route::delete('/skillset/delete/{id}', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Skillsetcontroller@delete', 'as' => 'destroy']);

        });
```

When i click delete button my console give me path like

```
DELETE 
XHR 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/skillset/delete/1
```

Can anyone tell me the solution please..any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not working means what ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz-Delete is not working .nothing is deleted from database

Comment: Inside `Skillsetcontroller@delete` put an echo and check if the execution reaches there or not ?

Comment: you have mapped route to DELETE, whereas your ajax calls make a PUT request

Comment: @gvmani:sorry for that mistake..i changed it but still unable to delete

Comment: @MayankPandeyz: i tried to echo 'hii'..but can't get the respond.please help me

Comment: Function should be 
 
 public function delete($id)
 {

 return $result= Skillset::destroy($id);
 }

Comment: @JYoThI : i have added $id but still same..thanks for your command..is there any issue with routes?

Comment: i think your route should be Route::delete('/skillset/delete/{id}', ['uses' => $namespacePrefix . 'Skillsetcontroller@delete', 'as' => 'destroy']);

Comment: @JYoThI-still not working

Comment: did you getting id ?  inside the function  ? echo $id;

Comment: @JYoThI-No.. i can't get..that is the issue..i can't reach that function

Comment: first of all did you getting token and id  in jquery  alert(id); alert(token); to confirm it

Comment: @JYoThI :yep i got id and token ..jquery is working fine ..and i got cosloe url like R 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/skillset/delete/1

Comment: Take a look on this .might be help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642044/does-the-jquery-ajax-call-support-patch

Comment: You have already prefixed your route with skillset in Route::group then why are you prefixing that again in Route::delete?

Comment: So you have registered URI in Laravel /skillset/skillset/delete/{id} but from JS you are calling URI skillset/delete/{id}.