# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php when send script tag

Tags: php, laravel

We have a HTML form that want we to send to the server.
Which sends a script tag like the following:

```
<div id="14871610107379120"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/NIM3h?data[rnddiv]=14871610107379120&data[responsive]=yes"></script></div>
```

I then get an error about this:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

How can I repair this error?

Comment: Print your routes write

Comment: route is good !!!

Comment: Show us the registration for this route in the route file

Comment: error is just  for <script> tag !!!

Comment: it's my route : Route::PATCH('/super/articles/update',['uses' => 'ArticleController@updateArticle']);

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be a problem with using PATCH method.

Since you are using a `PATCH` method. I understand that you have to add an hidden field to your form view so that Laravel can understand that its a patch request and not others:

You can use one of these:

```
{{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

Or this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
```

But because its already a url, then you can add `&_method=PATCH` to the url so you'll have:

```
<div id="14871610107379120"><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://www.aparat.com/embed/NIM3h?data[rnddiv]=14871610107379120&data[responsive]=yes&_method=PATCH"></script></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Note: If the answer I gave is the correct answer then this question is already answered here: [MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785670/methodnotallowedhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-219)

Comment: tanks , but it's not answer !!! this problem just occurred for exist script tag !!! i want insert a script tag to database with form but i can't !!!!

Comment: Can you add to your controller method to your question perhaps  what the problem was may be clearer.

Comment: controller method is good , the problem is this that laravel do not allow for sending <script></script> tag to controller !!!!

Comment: i do this works : add method_field('PATCH') , add route for patch method , a good controller method , problem is just about this that laravel allow for sending <script></script> tag to controller !!!!

Comment: I would say you could exclude the script tag when sending into the db, then whenever you need to retrieve the column where this record is stored, you can concatenate it back with the script tag. What about that?

Comment: If you could give an example of how you are sending the script tag to the backend. that is, maybe an example of possible your ajax code and the controller method that receives this request, then it might be possible for me to give a suggesstion