# Send only new values within ajax put request

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-rest-framework, dataform

I want to update a Django model instance using ajax PUT request and a Django REST API . What I want to do is to send only the values that will be updated within the PUT request. I used a Jquery DataForm object. But I get an error saying that there are required fields that can not be empty. Is there a way to indicate that those fields should keep their old values ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: use method `PATCH`  here example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461414/ajax-json-doesnt-get-sent-in-patch-only

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Django REST Framework then you can allow partial updates in model instances.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#partial-updates

Hope this helps.